# Unable to install tor: chown missing operand

Tags: 13.04, tor, chown

I get the following error message while starting tor:

```
flagg@flagg-eMachines-E627:~$ sudo chown -Rv $flagg ~/.tor-browser
[sudo] password for flagg: 
chown: missing operand after ‘/home/flagg/.tor-browser’
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
flagg@flagg-eMachines-E627:~$
```

I get this message or a file doesnt exist error when trying to run chown command

I am such a newbie and I probably screwed up while updating to ubuntu 13.04 or during the tor install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should solve the problem. Replace `USERNAME` below with actual username.

### 32-bit instructions

Install tor as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/tor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

Now change folder ownership of /usr/bin/tor-browser to your current user with this command:

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME /usr/bin/tor-browser
```

### 64-bit instructions

Install tor as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/tor64
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

Now change folder ownership of /usr/bin/tor-browser to your current user with this command:

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME /usr/bin/tor-browser <BR>
```

Thanks for pointing the mistake amc. Fixed it now.

Comment: -E627:~$ sudo chown -R flagg: /home/flagg/.tor-browser
chown: cannot access ‘/home/flagg/.tor-browser’: No such file or directory
flagg@flagg-eMachines-E627:~$        did all that and got this

Comment: flagg@flagg-eMachines-E627:~$ sudo chown -R flagg ~/.tor-browser
chown: cannot access ‘/home/flagg/.tor-browser’: No such file or directory
flagg@flagg-eMachines-E627:~$

Comment: is it possible i have screwd up and there is no home folder? or im in the wrong directory i have such a crappy understanding of the file system

Comment: No flagg... just changed the path use the above path again to take ownership... Use this... <BR> $sudo chown -R USERNAME /usr/bin/tor-browser<BR>

Comment: is there a way to vote for you for your help?