# Missing Operand

Tags: 12.04, chmod

I am new to Linux . I am trying to run this command

```
mhn@ubuntu:~/mhn$ sudo chown www-data/var/log/mhn/mhn.log
```

but getting the following error

```
chown: missing operand after ‘www-data/var/log/mhn/mhn.log’
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
```

Can Anyone help me to understand this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install tor: chown missing operand](http://askubuntu.com/questions/349326/unable-to-install-tor-chown-missing-operand)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The 1st parameter you provided to `chown` was `'www-data/var/log/mhn/mhn.log'` which `chown` tries to interpret as the userid to use, and looks for a second (or more) parameters of files and directories to operate on. Use:

```
sudo chown www-data    /var/log/mhn/mhn.log
```